# How can I shallow clone all files from a repository at a specific commit?

Tags: git

I am trying to <s>extract</s> shallow clone all files from a repository at a specific commit.  I would like to extract these files to an alternate location without affecting the HEAD of the existing repository.

This is the command I'm running to get those files...

```
git --git-dir="C:\temp\repository" --work-tree="C:\temp\files" checkout -f "e2f4b8cf188c87db6a11c6f421b06f701dd6b07b"
```

The above command works to extract the files I want, but my problem is this leaves my repository with a detached HEAD.

What is the best way to extract these files?

Possible duplicate: [How to shallow clone a specific commit with depth 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278902/how-to-shallow-clone-a-specific-commit-with-depth-1)

**edits for clarification:**

- There is an automated process that commits to this repository. (which is why i don't want to detach the HEAD)
- I want to extract all files from the repository from a specific point. (i know the commit id)
- I'd like to extract these files to an alternate location.

Comment: when you say extract - what do you mean? You want to get all files at that given commit, all files that are in that commit?

Comment: detached HEAD just means that HEAD referes to a specific commit instead of a named branch.

Comment: A commit is not a set of files; it's a set of changes to files.

Comment: @Nicolas: No. That's one of the fundamental differences between Git and VCSs such as Subversion: a Git commit points to a set of files, not to a difference between sets of files. Take a read of the [Git object model](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) for the details.

Comment: @joelnet It's not clear from your question what you're trying to achieve, and in particular, why having a detached HEAD is a problem for you.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear.  I have updated the question to add some clarification.

Comment: @joelnet: Right. Thanks for reminding me about this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having trouble telling quite what you want, so here are a few methods to get at a commit or the repository state at its commit time. Suppose the commit is `1234abcd`

1) Two ways to view the repository state at `1234abcd`:

```
git checkout 1234abcd ;# 'detached HEAD' state; just don't commit new work    
git reset --hard 1234abcd ;# fully reset to the commit, abandon uncommitted work
```

2) Zip up the repository state at `1234abcd`

```
git archive -o myfile.zip 1234abcd ;# zip up into 'myfile.zip'
```

3) Create an email patch from `1234abcd`

```
git format-patch -M 1 1233abcd
```

4) Output git patch format so you could reuse it (e.g. `git apply` will read the output of `git diff`, you can pipe the latter to the former)

```
git diff 1234abcd 1234abcd~1 | git apply ;# create and reapply the patch to the index
git diff 1234abcd 1234abcd~1 > outfile.txt ;# redirect it to an outfile
```

Comment: git archive is the closest to what I want to do.  I will extract the files I want without changing the HEAD.  for some reason I thought this would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the branch from the other repo (don't pull, i.e. don't merge the branches), then cherry-pick the commit from the other branch. That will take that particular change to the current branch & commit it with its full history.

More details on Git Cherry Pick: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick