# Git: get a particular revision of a git repository with depth 1

Tags: git

How do I obtain a single revision from a git repository *without cloning the whole repository*?

**Note**: this question [has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489173/how-to-clone-git-repository-with-specific-revision-changeset) [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278902/how-to-shallow-clone-a-specific-commit-with-depth-1) asked 100s of times but I have yet to see an answer that solves it since they all start with "clone the whole git repository". This cannot be done in my use case.

The best I can do is:

1. Find the `depth` of the commit.
2. Clone until that depth: `git clone --depth $depth $git_repo_url`.
3. Checkout and reset: `git checkout $commit_hash; git reset --hard`.

But this still requires cloning up to the commits depth.

Is there a way to avoid that and clone only a particular commit with depth 1?

Comment: Do you mean something like GitHub releases, i.e. download the project up to that particular commit on the master branch?

Comment: No, with depth 1 what I mean is to download the "code" at a single particular commit.

Comment: So you want to "download" only a single commit?

Comment: Yes, I want to "download"/clone/fetch the content of a repository at a particular commit.

Comment: I don't understand why you keep referring to the repository. Do you want to download the repository or a commit? or maybe just the code without the git history?

Comment: With the "the content of the repository" I meant the content (e.g. code) without the history.

Comment: Yes, it's been asked hundreds of times. Yes, all the answers tend to start with "clone the repository". The reason for that is that's the way `git` works. Continuing to ask the same question and expecting a different answer is a bit pointless. There is, however `git archive` to extract a particular revision out of an already-cloned copy of the repository...

Comment: @twalberg The answers should then start with "No, due to the way git works that cannot be done. You could instead do x/y/z but that is not what you are asking". I find it very confusing to find the same question over and over again, and no answers that actually answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with `clone` but with `pull`/`fetch`. See this post:

1. [How to clone git repository with specific revision/changeset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489173/how-to-clone-git-repository-with-specific-revision-changeset)
2. [Retrieve specific commit from a remote Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872486/retrieve-specific-commit-from-a-remote-git-repository)

   ```
   git init
   git fetch --depth 1 url://to/source/repository <sha1-of-commit>
   ```

And set `uploadpack.allowReachableSHA1InWant` on the server side.

Comment: The first answer there doesn't work in git > 1.4: `git fetch origin <sha1>` doesn't work.

Comment: After some research, it is the server side that matters: [uploadpack.allowReachableSHA1InWant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872486/retrieve-specific-commit-from-a-remote-git-repository)

Comment: Nice, this is exactly what I wanted. It requires git > 2.5. This is the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you do a reflog and git cherry-pick